# How to update MySQL database after view's value change

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, codeigniter

I got this sports website project written in Codeigniter/AngularJs and I'm stucked at the communication between view/controller/model.

There is this function that updates user points in view, then I should use this dataSavingHttp service to update the database also, but I'm really confused about its functionality

The View Angularjs controller

```
$scope.buy_salary_cap = function() {
    $scope.remainSalary = parseInt($scope.contestDetails.salary_cap/10) + parseInt($scope.remainSalary);
    $rootScope.profile_data.points_balance = parseInt($rootScope.profile_data.points_balance) + parseInt(1);

    dataSavingHttp({
        url: site_url+"lineup/update_user_points_balance",
        data: {},
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.content = response.data.points_balance;
    }).error(function (error) {
        $scope.content = "Erro!";
    });


    $scope.isDisabled = true;
}
```

The Codeigniter controller

```
   private function update_user_points_balance()
{
    return $this->Lineup_model->update_user_points_balance();
}
```

The Model function

```
    public function update_user_points_balance()
{
    $condition = array('user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $config['points_balance'] = $this->remain_balance;
    $this->table_name = USER;
    return $this->update($condition , $config);
}
```

Here is the dataSavingHttp code

```
vfantasy.factory('dataSavingHttp', function($http, $location) {
var wrapper = function(requestConfig) {
    var options = angular.extend({
        url: "",
        method: "POST",
        data : '',
        dataType: "json",
    },requestConfig);

    var httpPromise = $http(options);

    httpPromise.success(function(result, status, headers, config){
        var l = window.location;
        wrapper.lastApiCallConfig = config;
        wrapper.lastApiCallUri = l.protocol + '//' + l.host + '' + config.url + '?' +
            (function(params){
                var pairs = [];
                angular.forEach(params, function(val, key){
                    pairs.push(encodeURIComponent(key)+'='+encodeURIComponent(val));
                });
                return pairs.join('&')
            })(config.params);
        wrapper.lastApiCallResult = result;
    })
    return httpPromise;
};
return wrapper;
});
```

Maybe there is a simpler solution, but I'm really new in these languages. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask the person who wrote the `dataSavingHttp` service what it does. Either that or write your own service from scratch. The `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated and should not be used in new code. The `dataType` property is a jQuery ajax thing and is not used by the AngularJS $http service.

Comment: Yes, I should add that the template of the project uses also jQuery and AJAX. Thanks for the info.